# Generate XML with Swift 5 to Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, xml, xcode, xmlmapper

I need generate the following XML in swift 5 in order to post it with Alamofire. I tried doing this with XMLMapper but could not figure out how to handle this. Could anyone give some advice?

```
<SERVICE name="dataservice/transaction.getView">
    <PARAMETERS>
        <PARAMETER name='columnList'>PERSON.FIRSTNAME,PERSON.PREFIX,PERSON.NAME,ACCESSKEY.RCN,READER.NAME</PARAMETER>
        <PARAMETER name='filterTransTypeList'>1,2</PARAMETER>
        <PARAMETER name='fromDate'>2021-01-17 00:00:00</PARAMETER>
    </PARAMETERS>
</SERVICE>
```

best regards,

Patrick

Comment: Do you absolutely need single quotes for `name` attribute in `PARAMETER` elements?

Comment: @gcharita no, they do not need to be single quotes, they can be double quotes as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using XMLMapper, you can generate this XML.

Try the following model:

```
class Service: XMLMappable {
    var nodeName: String! = "SERVICE"
    
    var name: String?
    var parameters: [Parameter]?
    
    init(name: String?, parameters: [Parameter]?) {
        self.name = name
        self.parameters = parameters
    }
    
    required init?(map: XMLMap) {}
    
    func mapping(map: XMLMap) {
        name <- map.attributes["name"]
        parameters <- map["PARAMETERS.PARAMETER"]
    }
}

class Parameter: XMLMappable {
    var nodeName: String!
    
    var name: String?
    var value: String?
    
    init(name: String?, value: String?) {
        self.name = name
        self.value = value
    }
    
    required init?(map: XMLMap) {}
    
    func mapping(map: XMLMap) {
        name <- map.attributes["name"]
        value <- map.innerText
    }
}
```

Generate your XML like:

```
let service = Service(
    name: "dataservice/transaction.getView",
    parameters: [
        Parameter(
            name: "columnList",
            value: "PERSON.FIRSTNAME,PERSON.PREFIX,PERSON.NAME,ACCESSKEY.RCN,READER.NAME"
        ),
        Parameter(
            name: "filterTransTypeList",
            value: "1,2"
        ),
        Parameter(
            name: "fromDate",
            value: "2021-01-17 00:00:00"
        ),
    ]
)
print(service.toXMLString() ?? "nil")
```

or send it with Alamofire (using `Requests` subspec):

```
AF.request("<URL>", method: .post, parameters: service.toXML(), encoding: XMLEncoding.default)
```